# Backup and then wipe partition table from head of drive

Tags: partition, gpt, mbr

I have a NTFS hard drive internally attached to my computer and it's causing problems with the other Windows installation on my dual (or triple?) boot machine.

I'm not sure if the partition scheme is GPT or MBR, but how can I create a backup of the partition table using `dd` and then wipe it from the drive so it isn't recognized by the other Windows as it starts up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To backup DOS label (MBR) use this:

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=mbr bs=512 count=1
```

To backup GPT label use this:

```
dummy=$(parted -ms /dev/sdX print | tail -1| cut -b1)
size=$((128 * dummy + 1024))
dd if=/dev/sdX of=gpt bs=1 count=$size
```

To wipeout the labels use this:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdX bs=Y count=Z
partprobe /dev/sdX
```

HTH